# Absurd values getting stored in session files

Tags: php, session

I have PHP5 installed with apache2. I am testing `session data`. If I do `<? phpinfo() ?>` then it says that my session data is tored in `/var/lib/php5`. So, when I hosted the php file which will store sessions, I got a file names `sess_9849r843` in `/var/lib/php5`. When I am checking the value stored its giving me weird results. Below is my code:

```
  <?php
       session_start();
       if( isset( $_SESSION['counter'] ) )
         {
          $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
         }
       else
         {
          $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
         }
       $msg = "You have visited this page ".  $_SESSION['counter'];
       $msg .= "in this session.";
   ?>
   <html>
    <head>
      <title>Setting up a PHP session</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php  echo ( $msg ); ?>
    </body>
  </html>
```

My `sess_9849r843` file is showing me:

```
DQ6Hv2KiqHxNXBwlAK3s3e3F-vU0M1JeY-Yj7uH4mfo.
```

So, I checked my `php.ini` file now there the `session path` is showing `/tmp` but I can't find any session files in `/tmp`. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Comment: So, does the `$_SESSION` in your PHP code work though? Then its serialisation format is an irrelevant implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Your session variable is encoded, so other programs will not steal your info. You don't need these files, just `$_SESSION` variable in php

Comment: Yeah, I know that the data is getting encoded. How can I get the decoded data? Using `session_decode`?

Comment: @user2567857 - you're missing something extremely obvious here, or you're not telling us everything. As a programmer, you have no business dealing with actual session files. All you need is `$_SESSION` superglobal. What's written in the file is of no concern to you, the language takes care of hiding the info from nosy programs, if any.

Comment: No, I need to get the data stored in session files for further data analysis.

Comment: @user2567857 are you trying to hack something?

Comment: @user2567857 - no, you actually don't need to get that information. Unless you are trying to hack stuff like Justinas said, you have no business dealing with those files. Now, you can insist on not telling us everything or fiddling in the dark with raw contents of session files. It'd be easier if you wrote what exactly it is that you're trying to do, and then you'd most likely get an answer quite fast.